# How do I install Bitcoin Armory in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu, armory

I am trying desperately to install the latest version of Armory on a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04. I tried in Debian Jessie first, but something failed and it would not run correctly. Reinstalled my OS because everything online indicated that it would install on Ubuntu. So I downloaded 17.04 because I figured it would be the most up to date.

Followed instructions here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmUP26r-Pr4

Got all the way to downloading the program for Ubuntu/Debian and clicking on it. It opened in the Software Center or whatever and gave me a button with "install" on it. But when I click the button, nothing happens. It's just a button that does nothing.

Can anyone point me to a thorough and working guide to installing this on a new Ubuntu machine?

Alternatively, I have an older working version on a Windows 7 machine. The Armory version is from 2014. I wonder if I could just download the rest of the blockchain and use that to get the private keys? Would that work? I'm scared to update it and have it break at this point. The new versions have broken on every platform I've tried, including Mac. Thanks.

Comment: Have you also installed Bitcoin Core? As far as I know Armory is dependent on Bitcoind running.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Armory version is from this year, 0.96. If that is not the version you are installing, then you are using an old and outdated version. The most recent version can be found at https://btcarmory.com/0.96.0-release/. Download the one labeled "Armory 0.96.0 for Ubuntu/Debian 64-bit with GCC 5.3". To install it, you can open the terminal, `cd` to the directory containing the downloaded deb file, and type

```
sudo dpkg -i armory_0.96-gcc5.4_amd64.deb
```

You will also need to install Bitcoin Core, which you can get from https://bitcoin.org/en/download.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install ./armory_0.96-gcc5.4_amd64.deb` is a bit more likely to work: https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line/769542#769542